# Anchor tags not functioning in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm currently doing some cross-browser testing for my portfolio. Upon checking Internet Explorer, I discovered that all of my anchor tags do not function as links when clicked. I feel they are being treated by IE as plain text, with no cursor change upon hovering over (despite being anchor tags with an href attr in the dev tools). All of the links work fine in other browsers (i.e. Chrome, Firefox, Safari), this just seems to be an issue with Internet Explorer.

Note: I'm not using any external libraries. Just some basic CSS and Javascript that I wrote.

An example:

```html
<div class="column">
    <a target="_blank" href="some-external-url">
        <img src="images/picture.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have about 6 tags similar to this, all in the same situation. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is a link directly to the site: [thomasspencer.ca](http://thomasspencer.ca)

The links in question are:
1) The 'learn more' text on the landing image
2) All of the photos in the "My Work" and "Personal Projects" sections.
3) The "View Github repository" text under each personal project.
4) The "Let's Talk" link and social media links at the bottom of the page

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a few mentions that anchor tags without text in them sometimes doesn't work with IE. The solution usually mentioned was just adding a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`).

EDIT: Think I've cracked it

Your body has been assigned a z-index of -2. This puts it behind the index of the html. If you remove the z-index changes from you body you'll find it works.

Comment: I've seen this as well, but it doesn't seem to help. A few of my other tags have text along with an image inside them, and still do not work.

Comment: Interesting...One other solutions I've found is to do with how they are displayed. Could you try displaying anchors as block or inline-block?

Comment: All of the anchors I'm using are currently set to display: block. I will try switching to inline-block to see if that changes anything.

I've also added a direct link to the current issue if you want to take a look for yourself.

Comment: @BoardGameGuru Think I got it